# Regex for dictionary (hash) like index

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex for the extracting indexes from a string.

example,

```
Input: SOME_STRING
Output: []

Input: SOME_STRING[index1]
Output: [index1]

Input: SOME_STRING[index1][2][index3]
Output: [index1, 2, index3]
```

I have the following regex:

`[A-Z_]+(?:\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\])*`

But for some reason, this only gives me the last index. Any pointers?

**Edit:**

I'm using python.

**Edit 2:**

I just realized, it is not enough to just extract the indexes, I also need to extract `SOME_STRING`

Hence, input/output:

```
Input: SOME_STRING
Output: [SOME_STRING]

Input: SOME_STRING[index1]
Output: [SOME_STRING, index1]

Input: SOME_STRING[index1][2][index3]
Output: [SOME_STRING, index1, 2, index3]
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with this regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', 'SOME_STRING[index1][2][index3]');
['index1', '2', 'index3']
```

**EDIT:** As per the revised question you can do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^[]*)\[([^]]*)\]', 'SOME_STRING[index1][2][index3]');
[('SOME_STRING', 'index1'), ('', '2'), ('', 'index3')]
```

And iterate the resulting array and skip empty strings.

Comment: What if I also want to seperately extract SOME_STRING?

Comment: Hmm can be done but that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: Edited my answer, alternatively you can use `re.finditer` and ignore empty strings.